# preg_replace only string, not in a or img tags

Tags: php, preg-replace

So I have this php variable:

```
$keywords = array("google"=>"http://google.com","stackoverflow"=>"http://stackoverflow.com");    
$content = "<p>Hello Stackover flow</p>
    <p><img src='IMG_URL' alt='stackoverflow logo'/></p>
    <p>Let's go to <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>stackoverflow</a></p>
    <p>To use stackoverflow and google</p>";
```

How can I convert it to that:

```
$content = "<p>Hello Stackover flow</p>
<p><img src='IMG_URL' alt='stackoverflow logo'/></p>
<p>Let's go to <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>stackoverflow</a></p>
<p>To use <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>stackoverflow</a> and <a href="http://google.com">google</a></p>";
```

Comment: Do you have any other test data? You can't do a simple str_replace(), right?

Comment: This isn't a good idea.  There are many other places you don't want to replace an arbitrary string with an `a` element.  Where is `$content` coming from that you need to change it blindly?

Comment: Don't use regex for html. Use http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: I'm just trying to make a content tagging function to replace some keywords with links automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you to use `array_map()` & `implode()`. Example:

```
$keywords = array("google"=>"http://google.com","stackoverflow"=>"http://stackoverflow.com");
$content = "<p>Hello Stackover flow</p>
<p><img src='IMG_URL' alt='stackoverflow logo'/></p>
<p>Let's go to <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>stackoverflow</a></p>
<p>To use stackoverflow and google</p>";

$anchors = array_map(function($v, $k){
    return '<a href="'.$v.'">'.$k.'</a>';
}, $keywords, array_keys($keywords));

$anchors = '<p> To use '.implode(' and ', $anchors).'</p>';

echo preg_replace("/<p>To use (.*?)<\/p>/", $anchors, $content);
```

**Reference:**

- [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)
- [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I am very appreciated, I just updated the question to make to more clear.

Comment: Updated according to your modification. Hope now it will help you! :)